# Adding more mouselisteners to 1 JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mouselistener

Is it possible to add more than 1 mouselistener to a JButton? You know when I click on the button it should change color and text, and do something (e.g system.out.println), and when I click it again it should go back to the previous state, and print something else.

What I've tried:

```
JButton b = new JButton("First");
b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
            {
b.setBackground(Color.RED);
                b.setText("Second");
System.out.println("You've clicked the button");
}
if(b.getModel.isPressed){
b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
b.setText("Second");
System.out.println("You're back");
}
```

The problem is that the button doesn't go back to the previous state with the color (green) and text, and I don't how to handle that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be using a MouseListener to do these things, because a better listener, ActionListener, was built specifically to be used with JButtons and similar entities to notify programs that a button has been pressed.

Having said that, sure you can add multiple ActionListeners (or MouseListeners) to a JButton, or you can have an ActionListener change its behaviors depending on the state of the program (usually meaning the values held by fields of the class).

A problem with your code and question is that I don't see *when* you expect or want the button to change its color back to green. If after a certain period of time, then have your ActionListener start a Swing Timer that changes the button's color back to green after x milliseconds.

Edit: I see, you want to toggle color -- then use a boolean field that you toggle or check the button's current color and base the listener's response based on that color.

example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ToggleColor extends JPanel {

    public ToggleColor() {
        JButton button = new JButton(new MyButtonAction());
        button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        add(button);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ToggleColor mainPanel = new ToggleColor();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ToggleColor");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
    // !! parallel arrays being used below -- avoid if possible
    private static final String[] TEXT = {"First", "Second", "Third"};
    private static final Color[] COLORS = {Color.GREEN, Color.RED, new Color(108, 160, 220)};
    private int index = 0;

    public MyButtonAction() {
        super(TEXT[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        index++;
        index %= TEXT.length;
        putValue(NAME, TEXT[index]);
        Component c = (Component) e.getSource();
        c.setBackground(COLORS[index]);
    }
}
```

This uses an AbstractAction class which is like an ActionListener but on "steroids"

Comment: @adadudu: example posted above, but if you read any tutorial on coding with JButtons, you should easily see how and why to use ActionListeners. I've assumed that you've done this already though before coming here.

Answer (score 2):

You should only register one lister, but that listener will maintain some state regarding the number for mouse clicks. A simple if/else block will change the actions and change the text on the button label.

Comment: So basically I just have to put the if statement in mouseclicked?